# How to alter the column names of a loaded table with SQL without altering the original database?

Tags: sql, postgresql

I'm crossing several tables of a PostgreSQL database and loading a new table (SELECT). Is there a way to change the column names of the new table without altering anything in the original database?

For example, how could I change the name of the column "col_3" to "new_column" in the following SQL query?

```
SELECT table1.col_1, table1.col_2, table2.col_3, table2.col_4, table2.col_5
FROM table1
INNER JOIN table2
ON table1.column_t_1= table2.column_t_2;
```

Comment: `SELECT...table2.col_3 as new_column...`, but this is a simple SELECT statement. This isn't the usual meaning of *generating a new table*. You might want to clarify your question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
 SELECT table1.col_1, table1.col_2, table2.col_3 as new_column_1, table2.col_4 as    new_column_2, table2.col_5 as  new_column_3
  FROM table1
  INNER JOIN table2
   ON table1.column_t_1= table2.column_t_2;
```

It is called "alias"